# C++ while will not end after switch, Logic?

Tags: c++

This function that I have calls another function that doesn't return anything, then while statement should allow for exit from function if q is entered. It is not working. When I enter q or Q it prints thank you, goodbye. then starts the switch over as if while condition was not met. Any ideas?

```
void Watch::userInteraction()
{
    daysInMonthSwitch();
    char answer;
    while (answer != 'q' || answer != 'Q')
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "Enter r to run." << endl;
        cout << "Enter c to change time or date." << endl;
        cout << "Enter q to quit." << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        switch(answer)
        {
        case 'r':
            tick();
        break; 
        case 'R':
            tick();
        break;
        case 'c':
            changeTimeOrDate();
        break;
        case 'C':
            changeTimeOrDate();
        break;
        case 'q':
            cout << "Thank you, goodbye";
            break;
        case 'Q':
            cout << "Thank you, goodbye";
            break;
        default :
            userInteraction();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think harder about the condition. Make a truth table with random values.

Comment: Note: Undefined behavior. A valid initial value of `answer` could be `Q` which would not turn out well for this code. Initialize `answer` :)

Comment: Also: `tolower` may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (answer != 'q' || answer != 'Q')
```

should be

```
while (answer != 'q' && answer != 'Q')
```

You should also initialize `answer`.

Also, this doesn't cause any problems, but if you have two switch labels with the same action, you can combine them to save some lines by leaving out `break`:

```
case 'R':
case 'r':
    tick();
    break;
```

Comment: :sigh: You could have done that without giving a direct answer to an obvious homework question (-1) but a correct answer (+1) Total: 0.

Comment: It isn't a homework question. It is a programming project for school. This is just the main control menu. Thank all of you so freaking much! So helpful! Also thank you for the tip about the switch. If you saw the rest of my code you would laugh. That would have saved me a lot of time but it will save me 10 times that in the future! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Regardless of the code's ultimate target, *understanding* is much more valuable than copy-and-paste ready sample code. I think that's the point Billy was making. As long as you (Tyler) understand what was wrong with your original code and why this fixed it, all is well.

Comment: I understand your point. Why should I be doing this if I am not understanding it, retaining, and reusing it. Totally agree! I did understand. I had just been spending hours on this and I was having wicked brain farts at that point haha. Again, thanks everyone!